# Rails foreign key is is allways null after saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models,

```
class ProcessType < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :remarks

validates :code, :name, presence: true
end

class Remark < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :process_type
belongs_to :origin

validates :description, presence: true
end
```

The foreign key is set correctly, the **remarks** table has a **process_type_id** column.

On the Create form, I display the processes available using a select:

```
<%= simple_form_for @remark do |f| %>
  <%= collection_select(:remark, :process_type_id, ProcessType.all, :id, :name) %>

  <%= f.input :description, label: 'Description' %>
  <%= f.input :suggestion, label: 'Suggestion' %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My problem is that in the remarks table, after saving, the id of the process is always null. What am I missing? Is probably something obvious, but I am not able to see it right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :process_type_id, ProcessType.all, :id, :name %>
```

or, if you want to use the Simple Form methods:

```
<%= f.input :process_type_id, :collection => ProcessType.all %>
```

Comment: Tried both just now, same result, null in database.

Comment: Do you use Rails 4? Did you allow that field in `remark_params`?

Comment: Yes, rails 4. But I don't know what are you saying about remark_params.

Comment: Look in your `RemarksController`. Do you see a method called `remark_params`? Do you know about Strong Parameters? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: This solved it! Thank you, spent 6 hours with this one today.